# Tensorflow on Golang Model sessionn run error : nil-Operation. If the Output was created with a Scope object, see Scope.Err() for details

Tags: tensorflow, go

iam use golang with tensorflow model. With this code : 
```

```
    output, err := sessionModel.Run(
    map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
        graphModel.Operation("input").Output(0): tensor,
    },
    []tf.Output{
        graphModel.Operation("output").Output(0),
    },
    nil)
```

```

But show error : 

`2019/01/07 18:07:48 http: panic serving [::1]:55262: nil-Operation. If the Output was created with a Scope object, see Scope.Err() for details.`

I am already check `tensor` contain tensor from image file.
Any recomendation ? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says the `Output` attribute (of a certain the node) is a nil operation.

Hence `graphModel.Operation("input").Operation(0)` or `graphModel.Operation("output").Output(0)` returns `nil`.

To correct this, you have to refer to an existing node in the graph because there's no a tensor named `input` or a tensor named `output` in the graph.

From the python code you used to export the model you can find the complete name of your input and output tensors. Just access the `.name` attribute of your input placeholder and of your output node, to get the correct name to use in Go.

Also, the Go bindings are complex to use, especially if you want to run some preprocessing operations on the input image. I suggest you use [galeone/tfgo](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo)
instead of directly using the bindings (Note that I am the author of this repo).

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. @nessuno. 
Yo save my life :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to @nessuno great answer, that I needed to do: `my_model.inputs` and `my_model.outputs` to get the proper names. For example:

```
> my_model.inputs
[<tf.Tensor 'dense_1_input:0' shape=(?, 7) dtype=float32>
> my_model.outputs
[<tf.Tensor 'my_output/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 2) dtype=float32>
```

Therefore, my input and output nodes are `dense_1_input` and `my_output/BiasAdd` (not `my_output`!)

Comment: hi, how did you find `my_model.inputs` was it from python? I tried to use `saved_model_pb2.SavedModel()` object's `ParseFromString` method to read `saved_model.pb`. I am looking for input label and output label, which will I can use to specify `Operation("label")`. I also have looked into the tensorboard visualisation of the `saved_model.pb`